# как вернуть все индексы массива через return

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, нужно вернуть все индексы массива через return.

```js
function sel(){
let a = [123,123,123,123,123,123,123]
return
}
sel();
```

Comment: `return a` чем не подходит?

Comment: @Darth это слишком просто)

Comment: опечатался, индексы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function sel() {
  let a = [123,123,123,123,123,123,123]
  return Object.keys(a)
}

console.log(sel())
```

Comment: Спасибо, + нашел полифил.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sel(){
    let a = [123,123,123,123,123,123,123];

    return a.map((item, index) => index).filter(item => null != item);
}
```

Рабочий [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k970h3yh/).

Comment: а зачем фильтрация по `null`? Массив же будет цифры содержать

Comment: а без jquery можно?

Comment: @Duoxx, тут нет `jquery`

Comment: @ThisMan, для массивов "с дырками": https://jsfiddle.net/szxf5ez5/

Comment: @Duoxx ты где тут jquery углядел?

Comment: а почему так не работает `function _p(items) {
 let e = document.querySelectorAll(items);
 return items.map((item, index) => index).filter(item => null !== item);
}`

Comment: Потому, что `document.querySelectorAll(items)` возвращает не массив, а массиво-подобный объект.

Comment: И что делать ;(

Comment: как перебрать объект

Comment: @Duoxx, для начала, задать конкретный вопрос, отражающий суть проблемы. А на вопрос про индексы _массива_ я уже ответил.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, _"для массивов "с дырками""_ - неправда. Во-первых, map сам пропускает дырки и дополнительный кол для этого не нужен. Во-вторых, в дырках лежит undefined, а у тебя строгое сравнение с null, которое будет ложно. UPDATE: Разобрался. Исправь `!==` на `!=`, тогда да.

Answer (score 0):

Вернуть все индексы массива можно попробовать так:

```js
function sel(){
 let a = [123,123,123,123,123,123,123];
 let indices = "";
 for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  indices += i + " ";
 }
 return indices;
 }
console.log(sel());
```

Comment: а `jquery` тут зачем? оО

Comment: @ThisMan да по привычке добавил, на самом деле ни к чему. Исправил.